# Rest service call is not triggering the handler

Tags: java, rest, http, microservices, vert.x

I am writing an application in vert.x and Java.

I have a class in which I have registered the end points for basic rest services:

```
private void setRoutes(Router router){
router.route("/*").handler(StaticHandler.create());
router.get("/service").handler(req -> {
  getServices();//Call to Database and populate the services
  List<JsonObject> jsonServices = services
      .entrySet()
      .stream()
      .map(service ->
          new JsonObject()
              .put("name", service.getKey())
              .put("status", service.getValue()))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
  req.response().setStatusCode(200)
      .putHeader("content-type", "application/json")
      .end(new JsonArray(jsonServices).encode());
});
router.post("/service").handler(req -> {
  JsonObject jsonBody = req.getBodyAsJson();
  addService(jsonBody);//Persist the service
  //services.put(jsonBody.getString("url"), "UNKNOWN");
  req.response()
      .putHeader("content-type", "text/plain")
      .end("OK");
});
```

I am making a HTTP Get call to the GET /service end point as shown below and I am trying to get the response status code. But every-time the thread just gets stuck at the conn.getResponseCode() and then nothing happens.

Also my router.get("/service").handler is never called and in debug mode I can see that ResponseCode has a value of -1. From postman when I hit this url I am able to get proper results and also from the browser I can get proper results. Why is status code 200 not being returned. Also it does not go the catch or the finally blocks.

```
private void checkService(String key,DBConnector connector) {


 
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/service");
    System.out.println(url);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setConnectTimeout(50);
    conn.connect();

    
    if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        //Update the status of the URL to OK
        connector.query("UPDATE service set status = 'OK' where name = ?",new JsonArray().add(key)).setHandler(res -> {
            if (res.succeeded()) {
               System.out.println("Status updated to OK");
                }
                
             else {
                //Handle this properly later
                System.out.println("Failed to update the status to OK");
                
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        connector.query("UPDATE service set status = 'FAIL' where name = ?",new JsonArray().add(key)).setHandler(res -> {
            if (res.succeeded()) {
               System.out.println("Status updated to fail");
                }
                
             else {
                //Handle this properly later
                System.out.println("Failed to update the status to fail");
                
            }
        });
    }
    
} 
catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
    //Code to set the status to FAIL
   connector.query("UPDATE service set status = 'FAIL' where name = ?",new JsonArray().add(key)).setHandler(res -> {
        if (res.succeeded()) {
           System.out.println("Status updated to fail");
            }
            
         else {
            //Handle this properly later
            System.out.println("Failed to update the status to fail");
            
        }
    });
}
finally {
    System.out.println("INSIDE FINALLY");
}

System.out.println(" Done");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the static handler after your routes:

```
router.get("/service").handler(req -> {...});

router.post("/service").handler(req -> {...});

router.route("/*").handler(StaticHandler.create());
```

Vertx routers match routes in the order they were attached in. In your current state all requests matching `/*` which would include `/service` are matched and passed to the static handler.

https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_route_order

> By default routes are matched in the order they are added to the
> router.
>
> When a request arrives the router will step through each route and
> check if it matches, if it matches then the handler for that route
> will be called.
>
> If the handler subsequently calls next the handler for the next
> matching route (if any) will be called. And so on.